# How to enable text search in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I tried so many things..

```
# in replica set configuration, specify the name of the replica set
# replSet = setname
setParameter=textSearchEnabled=true
```

This is the part of config file. Still after setting this the text search is not enabled.

Am using pymongo for text searching
 This is my code

```
db.command("text", 'tracks' ,search=request.POST['content_search'], limit = 12)['results']]
```

My mongo version is 2.4.10. Please guide me.

This is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nidhin/social-media-widget/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/nidhin/social-media-widget/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 57, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nidhin/social-media-widget/socialmedia/widget/views.py", line 84, in monitor
    data = [i['obj'] for i in db.command("text", 'tracks' ,search=request.POST['content_search'], filter = test_data, limit = 12)['results']]
  File "/home/nidhin/social-media-widget/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 435, in command
    uuid_subtype, compile_re, **kwargs)[0]
  File "/home/nidhin/social-media-widget/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 341, in _command
    msg, allowable_errors)
  File "/home/nidhin/social-media-widget/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 178, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
OperationFailure: command SON([('text', 'tracks'), ('filter', {'publisher_desc': u'Blogs'}), ('search', u'box'), ('limit', 12)]) failed: text search not enabled
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this line to config file should work:

```
setParameter=textSearchEnabled=true
```

How do you start mongdb?

**Edit:**
I recommend you to check that:

- You have mongodb started with this config.
  You could check it by calling db.runCommand("getCmdLineOpts") in MongoDb shell
- via MongoDb Shell db.runCommand({getParameter:1, textSearchEnabled: 1}) returns  textSearchEnabled:true

Comment: I already did that.. Its not working. i use sudo service mongodb start

Comment: Do you have text index created?

Comment: db.tracks.createIndex({title:'text'})
The name of the field is title.. But this one is not working too

Comment: It worked. I edited the config file again and now it works.Thanks